# Trouble Integrating to Visa Direct

Tags: php, api, phpunit

My aim is to have an on line system where people can transfer money via visa direct and also pay for the services.

For this I needed to integrate to visa network. However, am having some challenges doing the same. 
Well, this is what I have found to be the steps towards integrating with them:

1. Create a sandbox account where sample code is provided on how you can hit their end point.
   My problem came when I found the sample code provided uses PHPUnit hence I have a problem testing on a browser. 
   The sample code generated for you can only be tested on a terminal via `./vendor/bin/phpunit..` My interest is to be able to test the same on a browser. Can this be done?
2. After you are done with the tests, you request them to be allowed to move to production. 
   I am yet to get to this stage since I am stuck at one.

A major concern is that the email provided for communication during the development journey takes days before it is responded. This makes the development journey a bit too long.

Has anyone done this before probably in PHP and would be willing to help me?

Kind regards.

Comment: You didn't hear it from me, but word on the street is you can use Selenium to do automated browser testing

Comment: @apokryfos I don't think he's talking about testing as in automated testing. I understood he just want see the application work. Bbm: what is the problem specifically? do you have a webserver installed? can you print hello world on the browser? if yes, tell us more about the error you're getting and what have you tried.

Comment: @Aus these are the steps from visa 1. `To install the dependencies run the following command :

 $ composer install`     2. `Then you can run the API calls using the command below:
    
    $ ./vendor/bin/phpunit`    I have a problem converting the terminal calls to do the same on a web page. Question, how can I convert the PHPUnit working to work on a web browser?

Comment: Phpunit is a test framework, when you run phpunit it will read phpunit.xml that tells it what functions to run. So ignore it. read the API documentation from Visa. if you see it difficult, post the api docs url here. Also you can look at phpunit.xml for referense how to use the api, but it will not explain much.

Comment: @bmm You can read up on what [Unit testing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_testing) is which may give you an indication as to why what you're asking should not be covered by PHPUnit.

Comment: @Aus so I can change the functionality to a web browser based? Well, let me try that out.

Answer (score 2):

Your work process should be like that:

1- Your code:

- You have your webserver and php backend.

2- Visa API:

- Download Visa api via Composer.
- Test if the api works by itself (isolated from your backend) using phpunit.

After running phpunit, you know your installation of the API is successful. Now you're ready to use it.

Note that the API vendor Visa have already wrote the tests and added phpunit package along with their api, so you just run phpunit.

3- Integration

- In your backend, instantiate a Visa API object (I think their API is a class).
- Do the function calls as per their API docs.

To write your code, you need to look at API, and use help from their tests and sample codes.

4- Testing

- Either use a test suit like phpunit or something else.
- If it compiles, it is tested ;) // Don't do that.